# What is the "subject" in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

A sentence from Longman Dictionary

> That smell of oil and candles and that light from a distant window and him on his knees, mumbling.

I can't make out the meaning of the sentence and the**subject**.

Is it from *literature?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a grammatical sentence. Longman Dictionary uses a not-so-reliable algorithm to cull their example sentences from various online sources with no human double-checking, so you often see sentences by non-native speakers, ungrammatical sentences, and non-sentences like this one.

Comment: Poetic or writer's style, maybe? I'd read it like - *That smell (of oil and candles) and that light (from a distant window) and him (on his knees, mumbling). Three subjects?* :)

Comment: Yes, it is very literary. And it must fit into a broader context where the lack of SVP is fine. Imagine someone complaining. It's almost like listing stuff: "That horrible movie and all the noise in the theater and my boyfriend with his arm around me, sleeping. That's what it was like." Descriptive speech.

Comment: What was the entry in the dictionary??

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a full sentence, because there is no verb. The whole thing could be used as a compound object phrase. For instance

> That smell of oil and candles and that light from a distant window and him on his knees, mumbling, are the only things I remember from that night.

Or, it could be used as a compound subject by changing the case of the pronoun as follows.

> That smell of oil and candles and that light from a distant window and he on his knees, mumbling, created a lasting memory in my mind.

Comment: Should it be "him" or  "he on his knees...'?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The way I wrote it that clause is the object of 'remember'. I remember him. I'll change it. Thanks!

Comment: It's from a book "They came from SW19" by Nigel Williams. It is preceded by "A lot of things were becoming clearer" and followed by "He must have taken me there". So you are right, it is a noun phrase rather than a sentence inserted to add more context. The style is rather odd to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify finding the subject is to remove the prepositional phrases.

> That smell of oil and candles and that light from a distant window and
> him on his knees, mumbling.

becomes

> That smell and that light and him, mumbling.

Which clearly shows that the sentence is about "smell", "light", and "him"

It also clearly shows that there is only one verb, "mumbling".  But this verb isn't part of the core sentence, it is being used as a modifier due to the comma between it and the possibly compound subject.  Even if you pretend the comma isn't there, the meaning is still wrong because a compound subject of "smell", "light", and "him" cannot all mumble.  The sentence is likely a bit of prose or poetry (where the rules of English are relaxed to provide more emotional expression).

So the sentence is basically "he is mumbling" but in a way that the "smell" and the "light" add extra input to the reader, so they can both smell and see the scene in which "he is mumbling"

Comment: It isn't a sentence because it has no finite verb. "Mumbling" here acts as a modifier of "him". Yes, he is mumbling, but it is not a sentence.

Comment: I agree, it is also not a sentence because it has three subjects, of which only one could perform the mumbling.  The main idea was to get people used to cutting the prepositional phrases to make it easier to get to core sentence structure.  Still, I'll update it because I don't want people thinking "noun, verb" is correct grammar.